# translating with UIPanGestureRecognizer while setting UILabel text

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm having problems simply translating a view with UIPanGestureRecognizer while setting the UILabel's text to the gestures velocity.

I have been successfull translating a view with a pan gesture like this (with the help of IB):

```
- (IBAction)handleGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender

{   
    CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

    sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x, sender.view.center.y + translation.y);

    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

But when I add the following line to this method the view stops translating but the UILabel gets updated with the velocity:

```
self.myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sender velocityInView:self.roundShape].y]];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the translation value you get from the Pan Gesture Recognizer is a relative value. Relative to the starting point when the gesture began recognizing the touch. So you want to do is hold onto the original point the gesture started at and apply the translation to that point, not to the view's current location.

```
- (void)gestureDidTranslate:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGesture
{
    if([panGesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
        self.originalPoint = self.movingView.center;
    }

    CGPoint translation = [panGesture translationInView:self.view];
    self.movingView.center = CGPointMake(self.originalPoint.x+translation.x, self.originalPoint.y+translation.y);
    self.label.text = NSStringFromCGPoint([panGesture velocityInView:self.view]);
}
```

I can't think of a time where you would *want* to zero-out the translation value to a recognizer while it is recognizing.

Comment: I think you might have misread the question or I misread your answer. It seems like by setting `self.label.center`, your code would move the label. I don't want to move the label. What I simply want to do is pan a shape on the screen and have the `label.text` set to the view's velocity of the pan gesture. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Btw, @elpsk figured out that Autolayout on my Xib file prevented my view from moving. Neither of us seem to know why but it works now. Do you perhaps know why Autolayout was the problem?

Comment: Oh, you want to move a different view, not the actual label?

Comment: Exactly. The label just displays the value.

Comment: There you go, move a separate view, show the results in the label. Github has been updated to reflect this for the full solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20593/discussion-between-samuel-goodwin-and-imaddin)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Label update properly.

```
@implementation APViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(Pan:)];
  pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
  [_View addGestureRecognizer:pan];
}

- (void) Pan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
  CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];
  sender.view.center = CGPointMake(sender.view.center.x + translation.x, sender.view.center.y + translation.y);
  [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

  _Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [sender velocityInView:self.view].y];
}

@end
```

If you have an `AUTOLAYOUT` on your XIB, deselect it, because view don't move. Why? I don't know.

hope this helps.

Comment: I tried `[self.myLabel performSelector:@selector(setText:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:[sender velocityInView:self.roundShape].y]]]` but there's no difference. I've read that UI changes happen on the main thread - does that mean that the translation of my view happens on the main thread as well as the change of the text property of my UILabel? They both happen at the same time. There must be a way to do this. Btw, thanks for your reply. I've been waiting for a solution to this..

Comment: Did you say that your code works for you? It doesn't work for me. The view doesn't move. As soon as I comment out `_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", [sender velocityInView:self.view].y];` the view moves again.

Comment: Have you tried my code in a new project? It's better if you post your full code...

Comment: I just did. Still not working. [Have a look for yourself](http://cl.ly/2v2J2S300H1V)

Comment: Of course not work. First of all, your variable names are wrong! `_aView` and `_aLabel` doesn't exist. Replace with `self.aView` and `self.aLabel`, because you have only properties. Next remove `AUTOLAYOUT` from your main view in xib. Build and run.

Comment: _aView and _aLabel works, doesn't it? When I create the properties for aView and aLabel it creates getters and setters that return _aView and _aLabel. (If you comment out `_label.text = …` the _aView will still move on the screen.) The problem was auto layout. Why did Autolayout cause this issue? Do you have an explanation?

Comment: Btw thanks a lot! I've been waiting for a solution for ages. And now it turns out that I had to uncheck a checkbox...

Answer (score 0):

With Autolayout!

This is all possible using Interface Builder.  Here is the code I used to do this:

```
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonXConstraint;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *buttonYConstraint;
```

Then hook up those IBOutlets to the Horizontal Constraint(X Position) and Vertical Constraint(Y Position) in the Interface Builder. Make sure that the Constraints are hooked up to the base view and not it's closest view.

Hook up a pan gesture and then use this following code to drag your object around:

```
- (IBAction)panPlayButton:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){

    } else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
        CGPoint translation = [sender translationInView:self.view];

        //Update the constraint's constant
        self.buttonXConstraint.constant += translation.x;
        self.buttonYConstraint.constant += translation.y;

        // Assign the frame's position only for checking it's fully on the screen
        CGRect recognizerFrame = sender.view.frame;
        recognizerFrame.origin.x = self.buttonXConstraint.constant;
        recognizerFrame.origin.y = self.buttonYConstraint.constant;

        // Check if UIImageView is completely inside its superView
        if(!CGRectContainsRect(self.view.bounds, recognizerFrame)) {
            if (self.buttonYConstraint.constant < CGRectGetMinY(self.view.bounds)) {
                self.buttonYConstraint.constant = 0;
            } else if (self.buttonYConstraint.constant + CGRectGetHeight(recognizerFrame) > CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds)) {
                self.buttonYConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetHeight(recognizerFrame);
            }

            if (self.buttonXConstraint.constant < CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds)) {
                self.buttonXConstraint.constant = 0;
            } else if (self.buttonXConstraint.constant + CGRectGetWidth(recognizerFrame) > CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds)) {
                self.buttonXConstraint.constant = CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds) - CGRectGetWidth(recognizerFrame);
            }
        }

        //Layout the View
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } else if(sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

    }

    [sender setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

I have added code in there to check the frame and make sure that it's not going outside the view. If you want to allow the object to be partially off the screen, feel free to take it out.

This took a little bit of time for me to realize that it was the use of AutoLayout that was resetting the view but constraints will do what you need here!